# Using `rack-rewrite` to Remove the Month and Date from a Permlink

Tags: regex, rack, jekyll, octopress

I've started the process of moving my blog to [Octopress](http://octopress.org/), but unfortunately, a limitation of Jekyll doesn't allow me to use abbreviated month names for my permalinks. Therefore I'm looking to just get rid of the *month* and *day* bits altogether.

I'ved read in [this article](http://adamwiggall.com/blog/2012/01/05/redirects-octopress-and-heroku) that you can use [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) to take care of the redirection, since I am using Heroku to host this.

So how would I turn:

This: `example.com/journal/2012/jan/03/post-of-the-day/`
Into this: `example.com/journal/2012/post-of-the-day/`

---

*Extra points:* If I had another rule that redirected `/blog/` to `/journal/`, would that rule still adhere to the above one as well? So from:

This: `example.com/blog/2012/jan/03/post-of-the-day/`
To this: `example.com/journal/2012/jan/03/post-of-the-day/`
And finally to: `example.com/journal/2012/post-of-the-day/`

Thanks for the assistance in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be as specific as possible, so you don't accidentally rewrite something else that would fail when it hits the new URL structure. Also note that I don't know rack-rewrite, so I'm following redroot89's lead on that point.

`r301 %r{^\/(:blog|journal)\/([0-9]{4})\/[a-z]{3}\/[0-9]{2}\/(.*)\/$}, '/journal/$1/$2/`

This captures just the year and slug, but finds the rest by more specific patterns. And by including the `(:blog|journal)` you can redirect both in one shot, without having to chain two redirects together.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought would be to catch every chunk between the slashes then just display the ones you want.

So something like this would work:

```
// given example.com/blog/2012/jan/03/post-of-the-day/

r301 %r{\/blog\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/$}, '/journal/$1/$4/'
```

Here's a link to Rubular to show what I mean http://rubular.com/r/La6rjrE5Hw

Comment: Thank you and great answer! I did end up picking Marty's though since I did like how `(?:blog|journal)` would do the redirection in one shot. :)